# POST date values in django testCase

Tags: python, django, testing

I am trying to write a test to sign up a user. I can't get the form to validate because I can't figure out how to submit a valid date to the form. Here is the offending code:

```
class AccountManagementTest(TestCase):
    def test_signup(self):
        response = self.client.post(reverse('register'), {
            'first_name': 'Gandalf', 
            'last_name': 'TheGrey', 
            'email': 'gandalf@me.com', 
            'password1': 'SauronSucks', 
            'password2': 'SauronSucks', 
            'birthdate': datetime(1956, 1, 1),
            'tos': True})
```

I can output the `response.content` afterwards and the error in the form is 'Please enter a valid date.' I have not overridden the `clean` method for `birthdate` in the form. Here's the declaration of the date field from the form:

```
birthdate = forms.DateField(
        widget=SelectDateWidget(
            years=range(this_year-90, this_year-12)[::-1]),
            required=True,)
```

How the heck do I send it a valid date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a *string representation* of the date which matches one of the default [`input_formats`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.DateField.input_formats):

```
['%Y-%m-%d',      # '2006-10-25'
'%m/%d/%Y',       # '10/25/2006'
'%m/%d/%y']       # '10/25/06'
```

In your case it could be, for example:

```
'birthdate': '1956-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, datetime and date are not the same object.
datetime contains information like hours, minutes, seconds unline date.

Take a look here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

if birthdate is a DateField in Django, you need to write :

`'birthdate': date(1956, 1, 1)` (don't forget to import datetime.date for this)